# Was bedeutet "nicht so krass der Fall"?

Tags: idiom

Ich habe diesen Satz getroffen:

> In München ist es nicht so krass der Fall wie in Stuttgart.

Wenn ich richtig bin, das kann wie "*In Munich ist not the case as in Stuttgart*" übersetzt.
Aber es scheint mir, dass diese Übersetzung eine Präzision verliert.

Und könnt ihr weitere Beispiele geben, damit ich besser diese Redewendung verstehen kann.

Danke in Voraus

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Etwas ist der Fall" means, as you already surmised, something along the lines of "something is the case". So, for example

> Es ist der Fall in Stuttgart, aber nicht in München.

would mean something like

> It/that is the case in Stuttgart, but not in Munich.

"Krass" simply is an adjective meaning something like "crass", "extreme", "stark", "rank". So your example sentence could be translated as

> In Munich, it's not as extreme a case as it is in Stuttgart.

or more naturally

> In Munich it (the problem, the situation, ...) is not as extreme as in Stuttgart.

Comment: Thanks, now I got it!

Comment: @AlexanderE Glad I could help. If you think this answer answered your question, you [might want to accept it](https://german.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer).

Comment: Note that the English translation gets the content right but don't represent the sociolect well. A middle-aged academic (like I am) might say the English sentence but certainly not the German sentence.

Comment: @Roland That may well be. I put the focus more on trying to keep the "mechanics", the construction principle of the phrase, than on keeping the sociolect.

Comment: I am not critisizing that. I just wanted to add information (as a warning for people who speak German as a foreign language).

Comment: Roland is right, it sounds like youth language.